# How do you exclude certain entities from being affected from a job system? (DOTS)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am quite new to using the `ECS` and `Job System` from Unity, so maybe I am misunderstanding a core concept here. I tried looking through the docs but couldn't find an answer (maybe because it's still in preview). Anyways, I want to be able to exclude certain entities with the same components from being affected from a job system.

**For example:**

You have a job:

```
            // simplified
            Entities.ForEach((ref Acceleration acceleration, ref Velocity velocity, ref Translation translation) =>
            {
                var deltaTime = Time.deltaTime;
                acceleration.value = gravityMass * math.lengthsq(math.distance(translation.Value, float3.zero));
                velocity.value += acceleration.value * deltaTime;
                translation.Value += velocity.value * -math.normalize(translation.Value) * deltaTime;
            });`
```

And you have two entities, both containing the `Acceleration`,`Velocity`, and `Translation` components. One of your entities is a space rock, and the other is a bullet. How do you make the system above only affect the space rock?

The only thing I could think of is to make different named components for the same sort of data (i.e. `BulletVelocity` and `RockVelocity`), but that doesn't feel like a proper way of doing things.

Comment: I'm more looking for the proper way of doing this: I also thought maybe I could just create a data component for each entity (i.e. `Rock`, `Bullet`), but is this how it's supposed to be done?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make two different components, one called `Gravity` and another called `Acceleration`.

**Edit:** In other cases it may be better to use [tag components](https://gametorrahod.com/tag-components/)